# Pass arguments through CLI while building plugin for intellij. I am using gradle

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, arguments, intellij-plugin

I am developing a plugin for intellij which I build using the command "./gradlew clean build" I want to pass the build type in the command and use it in the code. There is no main file in the code.I want to use something like "./gradlew clean build --buildType=prod". I am not able to get the value of buildType in the project. It returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Use the P flag like so `./gradlew clean build -PbuildType=prod` to pass Grade Project Properties.

You can access it in `build.gradle` via Groovy DSL

```
build {
    String buildTypeStr = project.getProperty("buildType");
    println 'buildType from -P: ' + project.property('buildType')
    println 'buildType from local variable: ' + buildTypeStr
}
```

You can access it in `build.gradle.kts` via Kotlin DSL

```
build {
    val buildTypeStr: String = project.getProperty("buildType");
    println "buildType from -P = " + project.property("buildType")
    println "buildType from local variable: " + buildTypeStr
}
```

If you need to access it in your JVM (or in Java Classes) you can use the -D flag to pass System Properties `-DbuildType=prod` and access it in Java via `System.getProperty("buildType")`

[Further reading](https://medium.com/@amoljp19/demystifying-system-properties-in-gradle-88c1991e72e0)

Comment: I have a build.gradle.kts file. How would the -P work in that case? and I already tried passing it as system variable using "-D". It wasn't working. I used "-DbuildType=prod" and System.getProperty("buildType") and it was returning null.

Comment: I have tested and verified it in my own build.gradle with the -P flag only, so give that a shot. I've edited my initial comment to include Kotlin DSL as well.